# RewriteRule Recursion issue

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in a htaccess file to rewrite the params out

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?unique=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now the issue I have is with recursion

`/folder/12345` - works fine and gets the value `12345`

`/folder/sub-folder/` - the index.php**strong text** file in here breaks with the above script

Anyone ideas how to stop it filtering into sub folder's **index.php** files?

Comment: How about `Options -MultiViews` or just add the following above your rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: None of these seem to work, it just appears to 302 redirect the subfolders index.php to nowhere and white screens me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, what is `12345` in you example? Can you add you complete folder structure.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a simple condition to check so the requested url isn't pointing to a file:

```
 RewriteBase /folder/
 # check so the request doesn't contain a valid filename
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # bounce everything to index.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?unique=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above will send everything that isn't a valid url to `index.php` while urls containing a filename such as `example.com/index.php` will be left untouched.

Comment: But what if you have valid (existing) files that you want handled by the index.php? Then you really get recursion. You can break the recursion with a "?" query argument, but then the GET argument shows up in the address bar. Or with a subdirectory just for the php files that should not be handled by index.php, but then your files MUST be put in that subdirectory.  Ideally, there should be a way of breaking the recursion more explicitly, but I can't find a method on the Web. I've tried to use environment variables, but failed. Cookies might work, perhaps. I've tried HTTP headers, but failed.